# Regular Expression for Multi line text area

Tags: java, regex

I have a multiline text area and I want to have a regular expression for XSS validation .

I want to know if the below regular expression is correct

```xml
<invoke name='matches'>
    <ref>eachFieldName</ref>
    <s>(\s*.*\s*['()&lt;&gt;]\s*.*\s*){0,1000}</s>
</invoke>
```

Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: So...what exactly are you accepting as an "allowed" input? Multline strings of anything? (that's what it will currently allow...).

Comment: Do not do any "XSS validation", simply handle and escape submitted content properly.

Comment: This is a regex for CSS validation text area without the parameter0and 1000 the regex works only for three lines and the regex does not work from the third line

Comment: So, did you work out the answer? We could really do with some examples of what you are expecting to work/not work. I'm afraid your description is a bit opaque.

Comment: What regular expression language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check out JSoup. This has great resources for parsing HTML, a task which regex shouldn't handle. I usually don't love filling up projects with external libraries, but this one is light weight, easy to use, and has exactly what you're looking for. Cheers!

Sanitize untrusted HTML (to prevent XSS)
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer